# yara-python cannot be imported to AWS Lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda, python-3.7, yara, aws-lambda-layers

I'm trying to import the yara library into an AWS Lambda function but I am consistently given the following error:

```
module initialization error: /var/lang/lib/libyara.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have tried adding a layer containing both the requests library and the yara library, importing requests works but importing yara does not.

The lambda function I am working with is as follows. It is doing nothing but importing yara at this stage.

```
import yara

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': 'Hello from Lambda Layers!'
    }
```

I have also tried creating a virtual environment, installing the packages, creating the lambda function and uploading it to AWS as a lambda function which gives the same error.

You cannot create symlinks in AWS Lambda for `/var/lang/lib/libyara.so` because lambda's only permit the writing to `/tmp`.

Is there anybody that has got this working?

Answer (score 0):

- Worth checking the way the zip file is created, Also check the uploaded zip if its in the correct format.
- The `lambda_hanlder` should be at the base of the root of the zip.
- User `pip install -r requirements.txt -t .` or `pip install yara-python -t .`

Comment: Yep, it's all correct. I can get other modules to work, its the yara-python module that doesn't.